# Android: Why does this Email-Intent not populate the receiver field?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am trying to send email by Intent and prepopulate the receiver field of the standard email activity. However, the receiver field is not populated.

My code:

```
private void sendEmail(){

    if(getEditTextEmail().getText().toString().length() == 0){

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.bitte_email_eingeben).setCancelable(false);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return;
    }

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    String[] emailAddresses = new String[]{getEditTextNotiz().getText().toString()};
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sende Email..."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are actually getting text from "getEditTextNotiz().getText().toString()".

Also, you can change this line:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

to

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
```

Comment: "getEditTextNotiz().getText().toString()" indeed gets text, I included the complete method call...